# Angular component outside of router outlet

Tags: angular

I want to show my error message using error component but don't want to load the component inside of `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` for an authenticated user so that nav menu should also not be displayed.

I have the app component like this..

```
<div>
<nav><nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And i have error handler which routes to error component using router.navigate.

But it loads in the router outlet along with the nav component. I want to load it as a whole page and without nav or any other component.

Whats the best way to achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, put it in the root component template. Not sure what you mean with the nav menu. Please elaborate, and describe what should happen when an error occurs.

Comment: i have the app component like this..
<div>
<nav><nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

So in error handler when i use router.navigate to my error component. it loads in the router outlet along with the nav component. i want to load it as a whole page not without nav or other component

Comment: I understand what you want, and nobody answered right yet.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a Shell-Component as the entry point for your logged-in user who will need to see the header.

Take a look at this [**Sample StackBlitz project**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sample-routing-eg).

If you have a close look at it's route config:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ShellComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: 'contactus', component: ContactComponent },
      { path: 'events', component: EventsListComponent },
      { path: 'events/:id', component: EventDetailsComponent },
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'view', component: ViewPostComponent },
      { path: '', component: PlaceholderComponent }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

You'll see that login is an outer level route where no Header will be showing. But as soon as the user is logged-in, the user is navigated to one of the child routes of the `''` route which loads up the `ShellComponent`.

So you can essentially create another route(`'error'`), at the same level as the `'login'` route and then navigate the user accordingly to the `ErrorComponent`.

Comment: Fyi, aux or named routes are not found when using empty-path top level route (with path:'') See: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10726

Comment: this is the right Answer. Thanks @SiddAjmera

Answer (score 0):

service with Rx very useful on your case, subscribe and show on root component, and you can append message anywhere, like this

**service**

```
@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
  messages$: Subject<string[]>;
  constructor() {
    this.messages$ = new Subject<string[]>();
   }

  error(content: string) {
    this.messages$.next(content);
  }
}
```

**component html**

```
<div [value]="msgService.messages$ | async"></div>
```

**component**

```
export class LayoutComponent {
  constructor(public msgService: MessageService) {
  }
}
```

Comment: i have the error handling code implemented. But this component loads in the router outlet. I just want it to be loaded as a whole page without the nav bar.

Comment: @AbhinavSingh could you show some sample code? I am not really get what do you want

Answer (score 0):

Just use a root-level route for the error page, so it won't be a child of anything.

Something like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
        { path: 'main', component: LayoutComponent, children: [
            { path: 'profile/:userid', component: UserprofileComponent },
            { path: 'settings/:userid', component: UsersettingsComponent },
            //....
        ]},
        { path: 'error/:statuscode', component: ErrorPageComponent },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: '/error/404'}
    ];
```

Comment: I have path like this only:
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'errors', component: ErrorComponent },
      { path: 'errors/:status', component: ErrorComponent }
    ])

Comment: @AbhinavSingh you don't seem to have a children components. you want to have more than one `<router-outlet>` in your project. look at [ngx-admin by akveo](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/tree/master/src/app) source learn from it. notice `app.component.ts` has an inline html template.